# Display list of printers and select the default one using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that will display all the installed printers on my computer. What I wanted to do next is that display by default as soon as the form loads the default printer on my computer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim objSettings As New Printing.PrinterSettings
    Dim strPrinter As String
    Try
        For Each strPrinter In Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
            cmbPrinters.Items.Add(strPrinter)
             End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmbPrinters.SelectedText = objSettings.PrinterName.ToString
```

If you put this on your form load, it will give you the default printer. Printer settings is initialised with the default values so will display the default printer.

Comment: that the answer but it's better to put this line of code after `For Each` loop